# eclipse can't install apk on device, "ActivityManager: /sbin/sh: am: not found"

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I'm trying to run an application from eclipse on a rooted acer iconia tab, nothing fancy, just a simple helloworld app, and I get this output:

```
[2011-06-28 21:45:12 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-06-28 21:45:12 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-06-28 21:45:12 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.androidbook.hello.HelloActivity activity launch
[2011-06-28 21:45:12 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: using device '37c618743c06297'
[2011-06-28 21:45:12 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device '37c618743c06297'
[2011-06-28 21:45:12 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2011-06-28 21:45:12 - HelloAndroid] Success!
[2011-06-28 21:45:12 - HelloAndroid] Starting activity com.androidbook.hello.HelloActivity on device 37c618743c06297
[2011-06-28 21:45:12 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: /sbin/sh: am: not found
```

I also tried running "adb shell", which properly opens a root terminal on the device, and I try to run the am command, I get the same error, i.e. "/sbin/sh: am: not found". However, the command is properly located at /system/bin, and /system/bin is in the path

```
/ # echo $PATH
/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
```

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Comment: try symlink /system/bin/sh to /sbin/sh

Comment: is that really safe? /sbin already has an sh. Besides, I tried symlinking stuff into sbin before and was welcomed by a "read only file system" error.

Comment: So, if am is in /system/bin try running /system/bin/am. Don't symlink sh because sh is not the problem.

Comment: @dtmilano, on a local terminal on the device, the command can be run simply as am. However,if in that same terminal I run /sbin/sh, and from that shell I try to run am, I get the error, even when using the full path. I don't know if it' relevant, but /sbin/sh is actually a symlink to /sbin/busybox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a "solution". Don't know exactly why the am command could not be run, even when it was present on the device, but after installing a different rom, the problem is unexistant. I was using the virtous rom 1.0.8, and switched to virtuous galaxy 1.0.2.

Thanks to anyone who provided feedback anyways.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the line

```
#!/system/bin/sh
```

Is missing from the top of the am file.
Just add it back using vi editor and it will work...

In case you have root you can use `busybox vi am` to edit the file. If the filesystem is read only then run `mount -o remount,rw /system` before and `mount -o remount,ro /system` after to allow editing of /system. You might have to prefix the mount commands with `busybox` incase it fails and prints the usage (which might mean you didn't have root).

Comment: ok, finally got everything working after modifying /system/bin/am and /system/bin/pm using the filesystem remounting, SSHDroid for vi (because adb shell in windows cmd doesn't work with vi).

Comment: the "am" file doesn't seem to be present on my device in /system/bin or anywhere else i looked. Will a ROM "work" without this file? Mine works fine for normal use, but this is the first time I tried to develop on my phone instead of the emulator.

Comment: Some ROM's messes with the system's files.

Comment: You can edit file right in place. Just type "adb shell" without(!!) any other command. After that "vi /system/bin/pm" should work.